# How to resolve "long time" to render template, "timeout error", "multiple users error" issues in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, timeout, gunicorn

I am building a website using Flask to then be hosted on [pythonanywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/). My website is perfectly fine when running on the localhost server. Since my backend process takes a lot of time to process (which cannot be changed) hence rendering template also takes time, furthermore, I am facing timeout issues in gunicorn servers Flask, and due to these long refreshing time periods, many users can not access the website simultaneously.

Can someone please let me know how should I handle this issue ?

I tried the below code, but it doesn't solve my issue.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(threaded=True)
# Alternately
# app.run(processes=3))
```

Could you please assist me?

Answer (score 1):

On PythonAnywhere there is a limited number of workers per application. If all the workers are busy your app can't be accessed by other users. For a free account, it is only one worker.

Comment: i tried it on google app engine also , yes i know it has limited workers but how should i overcome this issue for a long period of time ?